# Listview hiding behind ActionBar

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have tried to solve this issue but I am very new to Xamarin.Android Development that I think I am messing up somewhere

My issue is simple, My listview starts from Behind the actionbar as shown in the screenshot

[image]

My code is the following in which I have a list view

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomListView">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="#000" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/XMLlist1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:divider="#B7D3FA" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to add a `view` like this at the top of the listview to give space but it still does not work

```
<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:background="#000" />
```

any idea?

My Listview , Item is the following if that explains

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/webIcon"
                    android:layout_width="45px"
                    android:layout_height="45px"
                    android:src="@drawable/Icon"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Fox News ."
                    android:textColor="@color/listsub1"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_weight="0.6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2 day ago"
                    android:textColor="@color/listsub1"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/more"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="22dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/more"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/departmentTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Android"
                        android:lines="3"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/listtext"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
                        android:maxLines="3" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/newssub"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Android"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/listsub1"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/intrest"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="You've shown interest in iPhone"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/listsub2"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="2.2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/photoImageView"
                        android:layout_width="200px"
                        android:layout_height="200px"
                        android:src="@drawable/Icon"
                        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomListView"
```

And remove

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:background="#000" />
```

**Edit**

Use `android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` to add the `actionBarSize` height .

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it didn't change anything - Also in my `Theme.CustomListView` i dont have any properties, it was a place holder to be used later `<style name="Theme.CustomListView" parent="android:Theme"></style>`

Comment: Do you want to add ActionBar or not ?

Comment: Are you xml you putting is the whole ?

Comment: You are brilliant, thank you so much, I didn't realise I could add paddingTop like this. cheers for that,